Target title shown in mediawiki category list for redirected page
I have two pages Aaa and Bbb, that I want to be listed in Category Ccc.
Page Aaa redirects to page Bbb using #REDIRECT [Bbb#Aaa_specifics]. Both pages should show up in Category Ccc, so both pages use the [[Category:Ccc]] tag. The effect is that I see Bbb listed twice, under A and under B, with the first entry href-ing to Aaa and the second entry href-ing to Bbb.
I tried to add {{DISPLAYTITLE:Aaa}} in the page for Aaa, but still Bbb is shown in the category list.
How can I get an entry Aaa in the category listing as I would expect?
